# C# WebApi sending a request from Global.asax resulting in a 404

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I'm attempting to keep my web api application alive by sending a request to an MVC controller in the Api. I am getting the url in the Application_BeginRequest method in the Global.asax, then basically disassembling the URL and constructing it to hit a known controller method (route). When I get the url that it constructs and paste it in a browser the url works fine and returns the expected result. However when I user the same url in the application I get a 404 error.

Global.asax method that gets the URL from the first request:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!initialized)
    {
        var rawurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        capturedRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawurl))
        {
            if(!rawurl.ToLower().Contains("api"))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (locked)
            {

                var urlparts = rawurl.Split('/');
                if (urlparts.Length > 0)
                {
                    siteUrl = "http://";

                    for (int i = 1; i < urlparts.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlparts[i]))
                        {
                            siteUrl += urlparts[i] + "/";
                        }
                    }
                    if (urlparts[urlparts.Length - 1].ToLower().Contains("api"))
                    {
                        siteUrl += urlparts[urlparts.Length - 1];
                    }
                    if(siteUrl[siteUrl.Length -1] != '/')
                    {
                        siteUrl += "/";
                    }
                    siteUrl += "Labels/GetAllDeploymentLabels";
                    initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gets the correct URL. I have a timer which every five minutes calls this method, also in the Global.asax method: (it returns a 404 error in the message.

```
private async void  MakeKeepAliveRequest()
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WebApiApplication.siteUrl))
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(WebApiApplication.siteUrl));

            repository.WriteToApplicationLog("Keep Alive", null, Environment.MachineName + " : " + WebApiApplication.siteUrl + ": Global ASAX Keep Alive REQUEST  SUCCEEDED: " + message + DateTime.Now, Core.ApplicationMessageType.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            repository.WriteToApplicationLog("Keep Alive", null, Environment.MachineName + ": Global ASAX Keep Alive REQUEST FAILED: " + ex.Message + " ::: " + DateTime.Now, Core.ApplicationMessageType.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing, why can't it find the url from code, but works fine from the browser?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Auto-Start feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)? Seems like you might be trying to emulate it?

Comment: Not sure about what you're seeing, but I've had issues like this due to the hosts file or DNS not being configured properly on the deployment webserver. I always write a secret and protected developers-only page where I can put tools to help debug in production. One of the things that is useful to put there is a form where you can put in any url, have the server request it, and echo out the results.

Comment: The issue is that I am loading quite a bit of data into server-side cache, 20 minutes after the last request the application sleeps (in iis) so the next request hits the method that loads the cache all over again resulting in a long wait time for that unlucky user.

Comment: So I found somebody who was experiencing the same problem and this was the method he suggested.

Comment: UPDATE: I found that if I remove the exact code I'm using to make the request and put it in a console application it works fine. In addition this works fine when I run the application in Visual Studio, but it doesn't when I deploy it to the QA server.

Comment: Yeah, Auto-Start is a relatively new feature and I believe it would address your use case. Another possibility would be to use self-host rather than IIS (which can just run as a console app and be always on). Keepalive requests are simply not how IIS was designed to work. Your latest comment makes me think its almost certainly either a hosts file or DNS issue and has nothing to do with IIS, c#, or web api.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not running IIS 7.5...and I dont have access to the QA or Production Servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61783/discussion-between-rsh-and-george-mauer).